# Two application with a common storyboard on Xcode but they are different

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have two Master-Detail applications with a common storyboard file.
Build and simulate them, the layout of them are different.

All .h and .m files are common with two apps.
Directories are structured like following:

---

### Directories

- **/ Class /**

  - MainStoryboard.storyboad
  - AppDelegate.h & .m
  - DetailViewController.h & .m
  - MasterViewController.h & .m
- **/ App A /**

  - App A.xcodeproj
- **/ App B /**

  - App B.xcodeproj

---

### Emvironment

- OSX 10.9.4
- Xcode 6.0.1
- iPhone Simulator in iPhone6 (iOS8)

---

I can't find out what cause this difference.
Storyboard settings and properties should be all same between two apps,
so I wonder some build settings may be difference... :(

Would you tell me some point to solve this problem?

- [Screenshots (imgur : Click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQDXi.jpg)

  - First Image : App A Screenshot
  - Second Image : App B Screenshot
  - Third Image : App A & B Comparison

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the difference between both images is the scale, I would suggest to check the device (or at least) the screen resolution of the target device/simulator of each project.Given that the status bar (hour, battery level) is smaller in the "Second Image", the resolution in this case is bigger. If the resolution had been the same, the status bar would have looked the same.

Comment: Thanks for your considering.

I doubt whether build target OS is wrong,
and I confirm each app is running on iPhone 6 Sim.

First Image and Second Image are both 750 x 1334.

Oddly enough, the status bar expand a little bit when launch App A.
hmm...